# Can a sire feed from his childer without risk of the vinculum / blood bond?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, vampire-the-requiem

If I remember correctly, in the old WoD, a vampire could feed from its descendant bloodline without fearing the Blood Bond.

But in Vampire: The Requiem, I found no mention of that fact.

So, I'm interested in viewpoints, as well as references (books, pages, etc.)

**Can a sire feed from his childer (or/and descendant bloodline) without risk of the vinculum / blood bond ?**

Comment: FWIW, in VtM, a Sire could and did get a blood bond if they drank from their Childe.

Answer (score 7):

Although it's difficult to prove a negative, in all references to the vinculum I've found, no exceptions are made for the vitae of one's progeny. I would say that, under *Requiem's* rules, the blood of one's childer is not "safe" to drink from in regard to either vitae addiction nor the Bond.

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK, there are no exceptions to the vinculum rules except for those granted by specific Disciplines or other abilities. However, my play group found this to be very limiting in practice, especially when using high-level vamps that *must* feed from other vampires, and we've always used a house rule that states that vinculum is only a risk when feeding from vampires with an equal or greater Blood Potency. In this way, elders and sires can feed freely on those younger than them without risk of the vinculum.

Comment: There's a rule about this in **The Blood**, too, although it requires a Willpower expenditure.

Comment: There is a Vampire described in Chicago that has vampires pay him tribute, so that he is always feeding off different vampires, and does not risk a full bond with anyone. So obviously even elders have to take in this concern.