# Can a Sire be blood bound to his child?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade, vampire-the-dark-ages

I remember that the most important exception in Blood Bond relationship is that Sires cannot be bound to their childer. I have in mind that some Elders create childer only to feed from them, because that way they are free from the blood bond.

The problem is that I cannot find the references. I have found a small mention in the 1st and 2nd edition Vlad Tepes setting introduction, but no more.

So, do I remember correctly? In which sources can I find it? (Page number or section name would be very helpful).

Comment: This question https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5500/can-a-sire-feed-from-his-childer-without-risk-of-the-vinculum-blood-bond seems to agree with me, but I still need sources.

Comment: One cannot be blood bound to someone one holds a bound over.  Thus, a sire could blood bound all of their children and thus feed from them safely.  Kinda a dodge thus a comment and not an answer. Of course, the added benefit is that the children will be nice, well behaved, and eager to please.

Comment: I can't find a reference in the VTM 20th Edition, only that childe start with a level 1 blood bond to their sire. You can be bound to someone who is bound to you; vampires are known to create mutual level 3 blood bonds between themselves to try and experience "love"

Comment: I have a feeling it might have been in the LARP rules; but I don't have those anymore.

Answer (score 11):

**A sire CAN be blood bound to their childe**

In the 20th anniversary edition of the VtM rules there is no mention of Sires being immune to their childes blood bonds.

There is only two notable quotes regarding this in the text:

> First Drink (Level one blood bond) (p287)
>  
>   ...All childer have this
>   level of bond toward their sires, for the Embrace itself forces one
>   drink upon the childer; they may love their “parents,” hate them, or
>   both, but are rarely indifferent toward them.

And on the subject of multiple and mutual blood bonds (emphasis mine)

> A vampire can experience lesser (one- and two-drink) bonds toward
>   several individuals; indeed, many Kindred enjoy such bonds, as they
>   create artificial passion in their dead hearts. Upon the formation of
>   a full blood bond, though, all lesser sensations are wiped away.
>   ***Vampire lovers occasionally enter into mutual blood bonds with each
>   other; this is the closest thing the undead can feel to true love.***
>   Even this sensation can turn to disgust or hate over the centuries,
>   though, and in any event few Kindred trust each other enough to
>   initiate it.

Therefore: There is no restriction on blood bonds other than once a character is bound with a level 3 blood bond they cannot have any others active.

I have checked a copy of the Revised (1998) edition; and the text is basically the same for this in the bloodbond section (p218) No mention of immunity for sires to bloodbonds.

That all said I do remember from playing LARP that there was a rule (in our group, old UK By Night) that Sires were immune to their childes blood bond; but as written in the 20th Edition book there's no immunity that I can find after repeated searches through the document. I suspect this may be nothing more than a common house rule. It would also be an excellent rumour for sires to spread to the childe ;)

Comment: I know it used to be something more than a house rule. In Vampire 1st and 2nd edition introduction: *"I have already mentioned the Blood Bond, which is undertaken by drinking the Blood of another Vampire (usually one's Sire or Prince). It is known that taking the Blood of one's own Get carries no such bond,"*. I also have in my mind one introduction in which it was revealed that the second person was a child created for feeding purposes because of the immunity of the bond, but I don't remember where (Elysion? Diablerie in X?). What I don't know if it was outdated at some time.

Comment: I don't have a copy of 1st or 2nd anymore (donated ages ago) just a copy of 20th; could well be it's changed between versions or they left it out.

Comment: I suppose. Anyway, I wanted to notice you I finally found the text I used to remember. It's on my own answer.

Answer (score 5):

Many time after asking the question, I have found the text I used to remember.

> Though you must of course be wary of the witch­-hunters, it is the
> other Vampires whom you should most fear. The Blood of some Elders has
> thinned and they can no longer survive on mortal Vitae, but must feed
> upon other Vampires instead. Many of us create Broods so that we can
> feed from them, as we cannot be Blood Bound by our own Progeny.
>
> That is why I created you .... [sic]
>
> *Vampire: the Masquerade 1st edition, page 23*

It is again in a letter, and there's no mention on the system rules.

Comment: Well done for finding the quote!